# Notation for a subset of a powerset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If we have a set A containing all the integers between x and y, what is the correct notation for the subset B of the powerset of A where the sets contain between n and m elements?

For example if x=1, y=4,n=3 and m=4 then B={{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}}.

Comment: $B = \{M\subset A\ |\ n\le|M|\le m\}$? What are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$B=\{\,C\subseteq A\mid n\le |C|\le m\,\} $$
should be understood (the Comprehension Axiom may formally require to write $C\in \mathcal P(A)$ instead of $C\subseteq A$, but I find this more legible).
To get rid of $A$ as well: 
$$ B=\{\,C\subseteq \mathbb Z\cap[x,y]\mid n\le| C|\le m\,\} $$
or
$$ B=\{\,C\subseteq \mathbb Z\mid n\le |C|\le m\land \forall a\in C\colon x\le a\le y\,\}. $$

Comment: This answers the question properly, however I have to say that I can't think of a situation where I'd like to read $B=\{\,C\subseteq \mathbb Z\cap[x,y]\mid n\le| C|\le m\,\}$ instead of definition for $A$ and $B$ separately.